# Uninstall Ubuntu after dual boot - can't boot to Windows

Tags: windows, boot

I removed the ubuntu partitions using Windows Disk Management.
Computer isn't booting to Windows as expected, but I can't seem to solve this.

I followed [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/uninstall-ubuntu-linux-windows-dual-boot/), but it didn't help. I currently get INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE error.

Eventually, I tried reinstalling Windows completely, but that didn't go as well! I get "We couldn’t find any drives" error when need to choose partitions to install over them.

Didn't imagine It'll be that frustrating. What can be done?

Computer is Dell XPS 13 9350.

Comment: Which one is your primary OS before removing the Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Ubuntu was the one that booted as default.

Comment: When you try to `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`, did the operation completed succesfully? Have you tried automatic repair as suggested? What is the result? Remember that you should **boot from the USB** instead of the harddisk/Windows partition.

Comment: It finish with success. I did try auto-repair, which failed (didn't say why). And I am booting from the USB.

Comment: If the XPS has an NVMe SSD, it may have two different modes for accessing the drive - either "AHCI/NVMe" or "RAID On".  If it changes, that might lead to `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`.  With "RAID On", the Windows installer may be unable to find the drive without the right drivers.

Comment: If a regular Windows installer is having trouble finding the drive, you could try making a Dell Windows installer with https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/osiso/recoverytool/.  If reinstall from scratch, it might be worth switching to AHCI mode.  See https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/Pros-Cons-AHCI-vs-Raid-On-XPS13-9300-NVMe/td-p/7636984